# После первого прохода двумерные массивы перезаписывают сами себя, но только после второго символа

Tags: c++

Первое прохождение цикла while дает правильный результат, но на втором и далее 2-ой,3-ий,4-ый и последующие элементы массива имеют значение из последнего ввода. Можете подсказать где я ошибся? Пожалуйста

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <string> 
#include <cstdio>
#include "locale.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "iomanip"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    int z = 1;

    char x[10][20], y[10][20],str1[9],str2[9];
    int v[20], e = 0, i,i1 = 0;
    char c[10][20],c1[9];
    while (e < 1)
    {
        printf_s("Please enter name who was writed book.");
        scanf_s(" %s", &str1,8);
        *x[z] = *str1;
        printf_s("Please enter name of book.");
        scanf_s(" %s", &str2,8);
        *y[z] = *str2;
        printf_s("Please enter date when book was wroten.");
        scanf_s(" %d", &i1);
        v[z] = i1;
        printf_s("Please enter type of book.");
        scanf_s(" %s", &c1, 8);
        *c[z] = *c1;
        printf_s("If u want to write more books enter 0 ,else enter 1.");
        z = z + 1;
        scanf_s(" %d", &e);

    }
    printf_s("library list \n");
    printf_s("name     name     date     type\n");
    for(i = 1; i < z;i++)
    {
        *str1 = *x[i];
        *str2 = *y[i];
        i1 = v[i];
        *c1 = *c[i];
        printf(" %8s     %8s     ", &str1, &str2);
        cout << i1;
        printf_s("     %s \n", &c1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. `x[z] = str1;` - это даже не скомпилируется. О каком "прохождении цикла" вы ведёте речь? Почему на вопросе стоит тэг [C]?

Comment: Вот такие присваивания - типа `*y[z] = *str2;` - это не присваивания строк, а только лишь одного символа. Как и, скажем, `*str1 = *x[i];`

Comment: Благодарю за найденные ошибки. Можете подсказать как присваивать строки?)

Comment: @Vibronic если они объявлены как массив символов, то strcpy. Но раз вы пишете на c++, может все-таки будете объявлять строки как string, а не в стиле чистого си?

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, команда strcpy помогла. Я пытаюсь писать на чистом си, но не очень выходит... Задание на чистом си... Но, например, вывести целое число у меня не получилось использовал альтернативы printf(" %d",a) и сам принтф. Вижуал студиа не читает. Думаю и так сойдет.